# How to create System level iOS App to get other apps access

Tags: ios, sandbox

I want to create a system level iOS app. With the help of that I want to use the other Pre-installed iOS app information and using this information, I want to perform some task using my app and want to display that info over other preinstalled apps. Is it possible in sandboxed or non-sandboxed apps. I want to know the possible ways to integrate this feature either in sandboxed or non-sandboxed environment.

While exploring I found that due to security reasons We can not access the other preinstalled iOS apps data. I explored a lot but didn't find relevant information related to this.

Comment: All iOS apps are sandboxed. What you want can't be done. I don't know, but it might be possible with a non-App Store app using private API on jailbroken devices.

Comment: @HangarRash, How it is possible with a non-App Store app using private API on jailbroken devices. it will be great if you can share some more info on this

Comment: I specifically stated that I don't know. :) I'm just guessing that it might be possible. But I have no experience with jailbreaking and what world of private APIs that opens up. I just offered that as something you might want to look into if you have no plans to make this an app for the App Store.